# How to place an image on a point(x,y) using convax API in android?

Tags: android

I want to place a small image on the point below in code

{

```
   nineVline=new Point[2];

    p1=new Point(9*splitWidth,0);
    p2=new Point(9*splitWidth,height);
    nineVline[0]=p1;
    nineVline[1]=p2;
```

}

Comment: relative layout or ....?

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
layoutParams.setMargins(p1.x,p1.y,0,0);

yourImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

**this code is untested...

if u r using relative layout, then change accordingly.